# Parsing form with multiple checkboxes results on node.js and jade

Tags: javascript, forms, node.js, pug, checkbox

i have this form and i can't find a way to return the results in an array. How can it be done? I am trying to get this forms results so i can save them as a field in a mongodb document. I know the process of saving it but not how to retrieve it in a useful way.

```
form.form-inline(type = 'checkbox', action='/settings', method='post')
    label.checkbox.inline
        input#inlineCheckbox1(type='checkbox',value='en')
        | English
    label.checkbox.inline
        input#inlineCheckbox2(type='checkbox',value='ger')
        | German
    label.checkbox.inline
        input#inlineCheckbox3(type='checkbox',value='spa')
        | Spanish
    label.checkbox.inline
        input#inlineCheckbox3(type='checkbox',value='it')
        | Italian
    label.checkbox.inline
        input#inlineCheckbox3(type='checkbox',value='jap')
        | Japanese
    p
        button.btn(type='submit') Save
```

UPDATE

I've used on the server
var arr = Object.keys(req.body)
but i only get 'English' and nothing else...

Comment: What is the results you're seeing on the server side? You might need to specify `name='languages[]'` inside the settings for each checkbox.

Comment: i get undefined when i try to save the value of each checkbox or an empty {} when trying to get the plain req.body. I know i have to loop through them to get the checked one's values but don't know how...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Form type should not be 'checkbox'.
2. Give a name to each checkbox.
3. Use the specified names from req.body (they should be true/undefined).

Comment: Can you please explain it with an example? I get the points 2 and 3 but i should also not use form.form-inline(type = 'checkbox', action='/settings', method='post')?

Comment: Form has no formal `type` attribute. Just remove that bit.

Comment: Yes that's a great answer!!! It works!!! Thanks my friend!!! Also thanks robbrit for the try!!!